# Когда может понадобиться самому загружать классы в java?

Tags: java, jvm, classloader

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться с динамической загрузкой классов в java. Как я понимаю, при старте программы загружаются классы из rt.jar, потом загружается главный класс, а все остальные пользовательские классы загружаются по мере необходимости (например класс A загружается только когда в программе создается объект класса A).
Первый мой вопрос заключается в следующем: что собственно значит "JVM загружает класс"? Имеется в виду что в этот момент происходит компиляция класса?
Так же мне интересно, зачем JVM загружает класс, когда используется его статический метод? Я провел небольшой эксперимент: написал класс, в котором есть один статический метод и несколько нестатических.

```
public class StExmp {
static{
    c = 5;
}
private int a;
public int getA() {
    return a;
}

public void setA(int a) {
    this.a = a;
}

public int getB() {
    return b;
}

public void setB(int b) {
    this.b = b;
}

private int b;
private static int c;

public StExmp(int a, int b){
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    c = 5;
}

public static void show(){
    System.out.println(c);
}
}
```

Вызываю статический метод в главном классе `StExmp.show();`, потом запускаю программу с флагом -verbose:class и вижу что когда программа дошла до вызова этого метода, она загрузила весь класс. А почему нельзя загружать только статические члены класса? Ведь получилось что из-за вызова одного маленького метода пришлось загрузить весь класс, хотя он больше никак и не используется.
И главный вопрос: Когда может потребоваться самому загружать классы? Например с помощью `ClassLoader.loadClass()`? Вот этого я совсем не могу понять. Ведь если мы загружаем какой то класс, значит мы собираемся его как то использовать? Почему тогда нельзя просто использовать его в программе (например, создать объект) JVM же сама его загрузит. А когда это может потребоваться делать методом `ClassLoader.loadClass()`?

Comment: Ну например когда вы хотите иметь возможность не только загружать, но и выгружать классы. создаете свой ClassLoader, загружаете из файла class A, работаете.. и вдруг внезапно захотели использовать другую версию класса без перезапуска JVM.

Comment: @DmitryV. К сожалению совсем ничего не понятно. Как может быть 2 версии одного класса?

Comment: ох, к сожалению смогу только вечером нормально ответить с десктопа, если кто-нибудь другой поумней меня не ответит прежде :-)

Comment: Иными словами, @АлександрЕлизаров, нормальным людям никогда не должно понадобиться :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ну и топик. Про загрузку классов можно много чего написать. Тема интересная, правда, уже 100 лет теорией не занимался. В контексте треда, пожалуй, отвечу на вопросы конкретные. Если в чём-то не прав, поправляйте, критика приветствуется.

> Первый мой вопрос заключается в следующем: что собственно значит "JVM
>   загружает класс"?

У вас есть скомпилированные байт коды классов, `ClassLoader` их грузить по мере необходимости.

Зачем нам держать в памяти класс, если он не используется? Класс будет загружен только в момент использования. Точно так же, если на класс не осталось никаких ссылок, то `ClassLoader` может выгрузить класс из памяти при проходе GC.

> Имеется в виду что в этот момент происходит компиляция класса?

Ваши классы уже скомпилированы `javac`. `ClassLoader` в память его грузит. Это если в 2-х словах, на самом деле там происходит верификация байт-кода и т.п.

> Так же мне интересно, зачем JVM загружает класс, когда используется
>   его статический метод?

Статически метод, константы - это метаданные класса. Не представляю, как их можно загрузить в отрыве без класс.

> А почему нельзя загружать только статические члены класса? Ведь
>   получилось что из-за вызова одного маленького метода пришлось
>   загрузить весь класс, хотя он больше никак и не используется.

Предположим, есть у вас:

```
public class StExmp {
    public static void show(){
      System.out.println(c);
   }
}
```

Ок, давайте методом рассуждения выведем необходимость грузить класс. Вы хотите, чтобы метод `show` был загружен без класса. Но ведь в коде вы потом вызываете метод как `StExmp.show()`? Если класс не загружен, как вы себе представляете вызов метода? Ну хорошо, предположим загрузчик метод добавить в какую-то общую таблицу виртуальных методов. А потом вы создадите класс:

```
public class StExmp2 {
    public static void show(){
      System.out.println(c);
    }
}
```

Метод `show` загрузчик так же добавит его в общую таблицу статических методов? Проблему уже видите? Как потом при вызове `StExmp2.show()` понять какой из этих методов вызвать?

> Когда может потребоваться самому загружать классы? Например с помощью
>   ClassLoader.loadClass()? Вот этого я совсем не могу понять. Ведь если
>   мы загружаем какой то класс, значит мы собираемся его как то
>   использовать? Почему тогда нельзя просто использовать его в программе
>   (например, создать объект) JVM же сама его загрузит. А когда это может
>   потребоваться делать методом ClassLoader.loadClass()?

Например, у вас high-load проект. Приложение должно работать непрерывно. Но вам понадобилось заменить реализацию какого-то метода. Не перезапускать же всё приложение? Если оно стетйтлесс, то ещё ладно, но если там в памяти много данных/кэш и т.п.?

Можно заменить налету. Когда это надо? Ну, скажем, вы хотите поправить какой-то критический баг, оптимизировали метод и т.п.

Тут можно много чего придумать. К примеру у вас игра, в которой есть возможность добавлять кастомных npc. Вы просто пишите новые класс, который в рантайме подтягивается. Или просто неизвестно какой класс будет использоваться в итоге, решение принимаете в рантайме и грузите необходимый класс.

Бывает случаи, когда классы хранятся в базе (да-да, бывает такое). Их иначе и не загрузить вовсе.

Answer (score 1):

Итак. По умолчанию класслоадеров [всего три](http://samolisov.blogspot.ru/2008/01/java.html) но вам никто не мешает определять свой. Вам никто не мешает грузить классы не из jar или из файлов, а из БД или вообще через HTTP. Каждый новый класслоадер работает в своем неймспейсе, потому они могут загружать классы с одинаковым именем, но с абсолютно разным содержимым. В качестве "простого" примера:

Определим интерфейс Meower, чтоб не мучаться с рефлекшном:

```
package pkg;

public interface Meower {
    String meow();
}
package pkg;
```

И вот такую вот конструкцию:

```
public class Main {
    static String CLASS_NAME = "Cat";
    static String CLASS_V1 =
            "package pkg;\n" +
            "\n" +
            "public class Cat implements Meower {\n" +
            "    public String meow() {\n" +
            "        return \"Meo..ow\";\n" +
            "    }\n" +
            "}\n";
    static String CLASS_V2 =
            "package pkg;\n" +
            "\n" +
            "public class Cat implements Meower {\n" +
            "    public String meow() {\n" +
            "        return \"Mrr, meo..ow\";\n" +
            "    }\n" +
            "}\n";
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // Делаем из строки SourceFile
        SourceFile srcv1 = new SourceFile(CLASS_NAME, CLASS_V1);
        SourceFile srcv2 = new SourceFile(CLASS_NAME, CLASS_V2);
        // Компилируем и загружаем
        ClassLoader clrv1 = new MemoryClassLoader(srcv1);
        ClassLoader clrv2 = new MemoryClassLoader(srcv2);
        // Берем наш класс
        Class<Meower> clazzv1  = (Class<Meower>) Class.forName("pkg." + CLASS_NAME, true, clrv1);
        Class<Meower> clazzv2  = (Class<Meower>) Class.forName("pkg." + CLASS_NAME, true, clrv2);
        // Инстанцируем экземпляры
        Meower ov1 = clazzv1.newInstance();
        Meower ov2 = clazzv2.newInstance();
        // Мяукаем
        System.out.println(ov1.meow()); // Meo..ow
        System.out.println(ov2.meow()); // Mrr, meo..ow
    }
}
```

Иными словами, немного помучавшись и дописав какую-нибудь Factory я смогу(хоть и не рекомендую этого делать :)) в рантайме, без остановки JVM, брать исходники откуда-нибудь, компилировать их на ходу и менять поведение остальной программы.

Также, учитывая сказанное выше, можно придумать еще несколько причин вызвать `Class.forName`, наиболее распространенный - заранее прогрузить, а не затормозить когда вызовут. Менее распространенный - если вы грузите не с локальной файловой системы и хотите убедиться заранее что класс доступен.

ПС: исходники MemoryClassLoader и SourceFile  я сюда не выкладываю чтоб не получилась портянка, но они легко гуглятся.