# Загрузка классов в Java. Написание собственного загрузчика классов

Tags: java, классы, maven, classloader

Я хочу загружать классы из подключенного, собственного, написанного jar-файла, к проекту.

Конкретно где я хочу это применить.
Многомодульное приложение. У меня есть три модуля,к примеру A.war B.war C.jar. Где A и B являются родительскими модулями для С. Так вот что бы мне исключить модуль С я хочу загружать из него классы собственным загрузчиком классов.
Как возможно такое реализовать?

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/468575/16095

из джарника все само по себе должно тянуться

Comment: Указываете этот jar файл в classpath и будет вам счастье. Не надо писать свой велосипед.

Comment: Может я чего-то не понял, но что Вам мешает использовать C.jar в качестве библиотеки?.. Зачем заморачиваться из написанием загрузчиков классов?

Comment: Не совсем ясно, что именно вы хотите, и почему вам не подходит URLClassLoader.

Comment: @Nofate У меня получается есть многомодульное MVC веб-приложение. В котором есть два родительских модуля A.war и B.war, и есть еще один модуль C.jar, где A и B родительские для C.jar. Так вот чтобы не подключать этот jar-ник как модуль, я хочу его загружать как-то своим загрузчиком. Больше я скажу это направленно для "выпендрежа". Может его и не стоит писать. Но есть и писать, то как тогда? Если например этот jar файл будет лежать в моем проекте.

Comment: Я видимо что-то не понимаю, а чем вас не устраивает подключение этот jar как часть classpath? В том же мавен можно указывать его как отдельный jar файл, а не как зависимость.

Comment: загрузить внешний jar файл не является сложным, однако это вам ничего не даст кроме проблем. Поэтому лучше сразу напишите чем вам не подходит подключение "вашего модуля C" как dependency к прожектам A и B ? И еще напишите что вы имеете в виду под "родительскими" модулями

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как говорили в комментариях, есть класс [`URLClassLoader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html).

Конструктор принимает в качестве параметра **массив** URL адресов до `jar` файлов.

```
URL[] classLoaderUrls = new URL[]{new URL("./somestuf.jar")};
URLClassLoader urlClassLoader = new URLClassLoader(classLoaderUrls);
```

А вот работать с этим не совсем удобно:

**Загрузка класса**

```
Class<?> beanClass = urlClassLoader.loadClass("ex.coolStuf.Stuf");
```

**Создание объекта класса**

```
Constructor<?> constructor = beanClass.getConstructor();
Object beanObj = constructor.newInstance();
```

**Вызов метода**

```
Method method = beanClass.getMethod("sayHello");
method.invoke(beanObj);
```